# How to make my device driver load on system start-up?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

My hello world device:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

static int hello_init(void) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "hello world\n");
    return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "goodbye world\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

How can I make my driver to load automatically during start-up?

I can load it manually successfully using `insmod`, but I want it to be automatically loaded after a reboot. Do I need to use `Kbuild` and select it in `make menuconfig`, or do we do that some other way?

Answer (score 3):

On systemd based systems, there is `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service` 
which

```
[...] reads files from the above directories
which contain kernel modules to load during
boot in a static list
```

See [here](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/modules-load.d.html) for a list of directories used by that systemd service.

You can simply add a .conf file containing the name of the module you want to load at boot. The module must be correctly installed under `/lib/modules` and loadable with `modprobe`.

Answer (score 0):

Install the module in `/lib/modules/<kernel version>`

Add the module name  to `/etc/modules` if On Debian/Ubuntu Systems or Add the module name  to `/etc/modules.conf` if On RH/Fedora/CentOS systems

Comment: `cat: /etc/modules: No such file or directory` (Fedora 20, 64 bit)

Comment: `ls: cannot access /etc/modules.conf: No such file or directory`

Comment: Strange! Can you try creating one. Or I will delete this answer

Comment: Just try creating /etc/modules.conf and add your module name there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71488/discussion-between-tal-and-milind).